# python,django, solr, haystack: arg_parse error when editing solr_build_schema BaseCommand.add_argument()

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

Please help....i am trying use solr, pysolr and haystack on my django site search. I have edited the haystack build_solr_schema script to use BaseCommand.add_argument(), removing the default options_list. Below are my versions used;
Python 3.5.2
Django 1.11.11
solr-7.3.0
django-haystack 2.4.0
pysolr 3.7.0

```
# encoding: utf-8

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import sys
from optparse import make_option
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.template import Context, loader
from haystack import constants
from haystack.backends.solr_backend import SolrSearchBackend

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Generates a Solr schema that reflects the indexes."

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        # positional arguments
        parser.add_argument("-f", "--filename", action="store", type="string", dest="filename",
                help='If provided, directs output to a file instead of stdout.',),
       # optional positional arguments
       parser.add_argument("-u", "--using", action="store", type="string", dest="using", default=constants.DEFAULT_ALIAS,
                help='If provided, chooses a connection to work with.')

      """
       base_options = (
       make_option("-f", "--filename", action="store", type="string", dest="filename",
                help='If provided, directs output to a file instead of stdout.'),
       make_option("-u", "--using", action="store", type="string", dest="using", default=constants.DEFAULT_ALIAS,
                help='If provided, chooses a connection to work with.'),
       )
      option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + base_options
      """
     def  handle(self, **options):
         """Generates a Solr schema that reflects the indexes."""
         using = options.get('using')
         schema_xml = self.build_template(using=using)

         if options.get('filename'):
            self.write_file(options.get('filename'), schema_xml)
         else:
             self.print_stdout(schema_xml)

    def build_context(self, using):
        from haystack import connections, connection_router
        backend = connections[using].get_backend()

        if not isinstance(backend, SolrSearchBackend):
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("'%s' isn't configured as a SolrEngine)." % backend.connection_alias)

        content_field_name, fields = backend.build_schema(connections[using].get_unified_index().all_searchfields())
        return Context({
            'content_field_name': content_field_name,
            'fields': fields,
            'default_operator': constants.DEFAULT_OPERATOR,
            'ID': constants.ID,
            'DJANGO_CT': constants.DJANGO_CT,
            'DJANGO_ID': constants.DJANGO_ID,
        })

    def build_template(self, using):
        t = loader.get_template('search_configuration/solr.xml')
        c = self.build_context(using=using)
        return t.render(c)

    def print_stdout(self, schema_xml):
        sys.stderr.write("\n")
        sys.stderr.write("\n")
        sys.stderr.write("\n")
        sys.stderr.write("Save the following output to 'schema.xml' and place it in your Solr configuration directory.\n")
        sys.stderr.write("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
        sys.stderr.write("\n")
        print(schema_xml)

    def write_file(self, filename, schema_xml):
        schema_file = open(filename, 'w')
        schema_file.write(schema_xml)
        schema_file.close()
```

The error is gives is given below as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 275, in run_from_argv
    parser = self.create_parser(argv[0], argv[1])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in create_parser
    self.add_arguments(parser)
File "/home/tochie/virtual_django/myblog_env/mysite/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/build_solr_schema.py", line 22, in add_arguments
    help='If provided, directs output to a file instead of stdout.',),
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/argparse.py", line 1344, in add_argument
    raise ValueError('%r is not callable' % (type_func,))
ValueError: 'string' is not callable
```

Please help if there is any other way of solving this issue,without having to edit haystack's build_solr_schema or any other solution to this problem..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `type` argument. As the name suggests, it needs to be the python type `str` and not the python string `'string'` . Meaning this is what you need

```
def add_arguments(self, parser):
    # positional arguments
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--filename", action="store", type=str, dest="filename",
                        help='If provided, directs output to a file instead of stdout.', )
    # optional positional arguments

    parser.add_argument("-u", "--using", action="store", type=str, dest="using",
                        default=constants.DEFAULT_ALIAS, help='If provided, chooses a connection to work with.')
```

When you do pass `type` as a string, and not the type `str`, `argparse` assumes you are supplying a callable for execution. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type

> type= can take any callable that takes a single string argument and
>   returns the converted value:

```
def perfect_square(string):
    value = int(string)
    sqrt = math.sqrt(value)
    if sqrt != int(sqrt):
        msg = "%r is not a perfect square" % string
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)
    return value

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('foo', type=perfect_square)
parser.parse_args(['9'])

parser.parse_args(['7'])
```

Comment: @EmeasobaTochi Thanks! Can you please accept and/or upvote the answer since it worked?